# Google swiffy HTML5 banner clickTAG setting for google double click

Tags: html, banner, google-swiffy

I have converted flash banner into HTML 5 banner through google swiffy.
I wanted to set clickTAG and wanted to publish with google double click.

I have followed guidelines from this link,
https://support.google.com/dcm/partner/answer/3145300?hl=en

Guide lines  is as below,

Here's an example of a click tag inserted in an HTML document:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name=”ad.size” content=”width=300,height=250”>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var clickTag = "http://www.google.com";
  </script>
</head>
[The rest of your creative code goes here.]

</html>
```

Make sure your creative uses the click tag variable as the click-through URL:

```html
<a href="javascript:window.open(window.clickTag)">
<img src="images/dclk.png" border=0>
</a>
```

when i am clicking on banner clickTAG url is opening on new tab that is fine. but on original banner page tab is redirected to url "javascript:window.open(window.clickTag)" & displays [object Window] in page content.

Please Help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to look on that rest of code the line that cantains: stage.start();
right above this line you put this:
stage.setFlashVars("clickTAG=%%CLICK_URL_ESC%%http://websiteURL.com");

Comment: Thanks for reply,

Is it necessary to add hardcoded URL? 

If i want to use a varialbe value of url that will replace while i publish creatives on DFP. Is this possible?